# Ubuntu Server 22.04 has two IP addresses

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, netplan, static-ip

My Ubuntu Server has over LAN (eth0) two IPv4 addresses from one day to another. Maybe this happened with an update. I use it as a web server for WordPress and local DNS with Pi-Hole. All services are working normally.
System information at login:

```
 Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1024-raspi aarch64)
 
  * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com  * Management:    
 https://landscape.canonical.com  * Support:       
 https://ubuntu.com/advantage
 
   System information as of Wed Feb 22 17:28:28 CET 2023
 
   System load:  0.1796875           Processes:             168   Usage
 of /:   12.0% of 234.32GB   Users logged in:       0   Memory usage:
 27%                 IPv4 address for eth0: 169.254.99.100   Swap
 usage:   0%                  IPv4 address for eth0: 192.168.7.100  
 Temperature:  34.1 C
 
  * Strictly confined Kubernetes makes edge and IoT secure. Learn how
 MicroK8s    just raised the bar for easy, resilient and secure K8s
 cluster deployment.
 
    https://ubuntu.com/engage/secure-kubernetes-at-the-edge
 
  * Introducing Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications.   
 Receive updates to over 25,000 software packages with your    Ubuntu
 Pro subscription. Free for personal use.
 
      https://ubuntu.com/pro
 
 Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.
 
 0 updates can be applied immediately.
 
 3 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps. Learn more
 about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm
```

Static IP *192.168.7.100* is set at `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`
There is no other *yaml file in this folder.

Netplan settings:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            link-local: [ ipv4 ]
            addresses:
            - 192.168.7.100/24
            dhcp4: false
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.7.1
                - 8.8.8.8
            routes:
              - to: default
                via: 192.168.7.1
    version: 2
```

Why does my server have a second IPv4 *169.254.99.100* and is it possible to remove this second IP?

Results of `ip route` and `ip a` :

```
alexadmin@ubuntuserver:/etc/netplan$ ip route
default via 192.168.7.1 dev eth0 proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.99.100 metric 2048 
192.168.7.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.7.100 
alexadmin@ubuntuserver:/etc/netplan$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:a5:6f:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.99.100/16 metric 2048 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.7.100/24 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:a5:6f:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

After removing `link-local: [ ipv4 ]` in netplan, result of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:a5:6f:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.7.100/24 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd35:2cf:f17a:4a41:dea6:32ff:fea5:6fbe/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1741sec preferred_lft 1741sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fea5:6fbe/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:a5:6f:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: @Pilot6: Ok, sorry I have replaced the sceenshots.

Comment: @user535733 It is a private address.

Comment: @user535733: No this is not my external IP. According to my FritzBox Router I have 93.* as my external IP address. Router is setup for DHCP with 192.168.7.* All clients in my network has this address and there is no 169.* IP shown in Network section at Fritzbox. I have checked my notebook is has only IP 192.168.7.92.
Strange is, I can ping 169.254.99.100 from my notebook. Tested it also on a windows machine. I could also ping 169.* IP.

Comment: 169.254.x.y is a link-local address which you declared in netplan. Try removing: `link-local: [ ipv4 ]` follow with: `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply` Check again: `ip a` Is the problem resolved?

Comment: @chili555 I did as you wrote. The IPv4 link-local address is gone but now I have a IPv6. Is this now the link-local address as IPv6? On my router I have disable IPv6 for my network. 

I have add above what `ip a` shows now.

Comment: Evidently, you did not properly disable IPv6 in the router because you have what appears to be a vaild address. Test: `ping6 -c3 www.google.com` If you get returns, you are getting a vaiid IPv6 address. I don't understand why you'd want to disable it at all. Since your original question is solved, I'll write an answer that I hope you'll accept.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you very much for your input. 
As you wrote the 169.* IPv4 address is gone after editing netplan. I will check my network about IPv6 and if needed I will create new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your netplan file, you included:

```
link-local: [ ipv4 ]
```

The result was that you received the usual link local IPv4 address 169.254.x.y. I suggested that you remove that line. You no longer have an IPv4 link local address:

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:a5:6f:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.7.100/24 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
etc.
```

If you have futher questions about your IPv6 address, please start a new question.